# Cannot edit .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

So I had some issues regarding my website security and my host provider added this to my *.htaccess* until I solve the issues:

```
deny from all 
allow from 10x.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now, I solved my issues, but cannot edit the file to remove those lines.
I tried everything, even to delete the file, but no, operation forbidden. 
`public_html` has 777
*.htaccess* has 644
The issue is that allow from `10x.xxx.xxx.xxx` has my home IP and now I am at work, so a different IP. Is there any way to remove those lines from a different IP or do I have to wait until I get back home?

Comment: Whether you are at home or at work (ie. a different IP) should not matter. The .htaccess file does not "execute" when accessing over FTP - if that is what you are implying.

Comment: yes, it was only the root who had access

Comment: The host has the ability to automatically and manually allow or block IP's. I would communicate with them to see if they have done something beyond just the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that they have edited the `.htaccess` as root user and your FTP user will not have permissions to override `root` (no other user will) so unless you also have root access, you'll have to ask them to change the owner of the file to your FTP user so you can edit it.

Comment: that was it. :)